# LinkedList test

Tags: java, list, hyperlink

```
public X get(int index)
{
    if (index >= 0)
    {
        Node<X> i = head;
        int c = 0;


        while (c < index)
        {
            i = i.getLink();
            c++;
        }

        return i.getValue();
    }
    else
    {
        throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException();
    }
}
```

.

```
@Test
public void testGet12()
{
    LList<String> b = new LList<String>();
    b.add("str1");
    b.add("str2");
    b.add("str3");
    b.add("str4");
    b.add("str5");
    b.add("str6");
    b.add("str7");
    b.add("str8");
    b.add("str9");
    b.add("str10");
    b.add("str11");
    b.add("str12");
    assertEquals("str8", b.get(7));
    assertEquals("str12", b.get(11));
    assertEquals("str1", b.get(0));
}
```

It is saying that it's expecting str8, but is getting str5, why is my index off by 3? Am i missing something here? To me it seems when it doesnt reach the index it goes up one link until it finally reaches it then spits out the value.

Comment: Use pen and paper to mark your state after each `add`.

Comment: share the logic written for add()

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class list {
     static List<String> a=new ArrayList<String>();
    public String getvalue(int index)
    {
        return a.get(index);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
      list e=new list();
        a.add("Str0");
        a.add("Str1");
        a.add("Str2");
        a.add("Str3");
        a.add("Str4");
        a.add("Str5");
        a.add("Str6");
        a.add("Str7");
        a.add("Str8");


        if("Str6".equals(e.getvalue(6))){
            System.out.println("true");
        }
        else
                System.out.println("Wrong");







    }
}
```

Comment: Describe your vision of "normal" code. You are obviously not familiar with OOP or unit testing or even with usage of modifiers in Java. This is hilarious.

Comment: Im not familar with unit testing but yes oops i am familar.Just was trying to help thats it.He wanted to know about indexes of a List.
I did not take it as generic i used string.Assertequals i know it is in JUnit.I do not know much on it so i wrote a if() thats it:) 
If you feel if this was really really sad u may make it not useful